# .NET does not want to connect to OpenLDAP over LDAPS

Tags: vb.net, ldap, bind, openldap

I am currently very much stuck on trying to connect to an OpenLDAP Server using the **.NET Framework 3.0**.

I am using the following code:

```
Dim ldapDirectoryIdentifier As New System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldap.example.de", 636, True, False)
connection = New LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier)
connection.AuthType = 2 '//Negotiate
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = True

'//This is set to true temporarily for test purposes
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = true
connection.Credential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("cn=LDAP_user,ou=Funktion-User,o=Comp", "******")             
connection.Bind()
```

The output is **"The supplied credentials are invalid"**, but entering the very same credentials into any other tool works quite fine.

I have also tried:

- Username: "`LDAP_user`"
- Username:
  "`cn=LDAP_user,ou=Funktion-User,o=Comp,dc=example,dc=de`"
- AuthType:
  1-7
- A different user altogether
- ProcotolVersion = 2
- a non-fully qualified hostname

I have tried every variable, and I am out of ideas.

Comment: Is there any other information in the exception, particularly a "data" value?

Comment: Why do you set VerifyServerCertificate property? It cannot take true/false value according to MS

Comment: @Vasya Apologies, it points to a function that, in this particular test case, returns always true.

Comment: @GabrielLuci There is no further informaton in the exception